# How to display multiple <options> through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have almost no experience using Jquery (or even Javascript), but after doing some research, it seems I need it. I have a HTML form to select a country and region, but I need the selection for country to determine what populates the region list.

> ```
> <select name="search_country" id="scid">
>   <option value="">Select a country</option>
>   <option value="cyprus">Cyprus</option>
>   <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
>   <option value="greece">Greece</option>
> </select>
> <select name="search_region" id="srid">
>   <option value="">Select a region</option>
> </select>
> ```

After looking around this site, I found some code which almost completely works, but when a country is selected, only one of the regions (the top option) shows up on the list.

```
$(function(){
 $("#scid").change(function(){
var options = '';
if($(this).val().indexOf('cyprus') > -1) {
    options = '<option value="paphos">Paphos</option>';
              '<option value="larnaca">Larnaca</option>';
              '<option value="nicosia">Nicosia</option>';
              '<option value="agia_napa">Agia Napa</option>';
}
else if ($(this).val().indexOf('turkey') > -1) {
    options = '<option value="ankara">Ankara</option>';
}
    else if ($(this).val().indexOf('greece') > -1) {
    options = '<option value="athens">Athens</option>';
              '<option value="rhodes">Rhodes</option>';
}
$('#srid').html(options); }); });
```

What can I do so that all the appropriate regions fill the second drop down list when their country is selected?

Thanks.

Comment: You should concatenate them as a single string.

Comment: Replace the semicolon after `</option>` with `+` instead.

Comment: As already noted by others, replace the semi-colons with + signs to join them together. As yours looks right now, you have a statement saying the `options = '<option value="paphos">Paphos</option>;` for example. and then completely separate statements with just strings that aren't set to anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't *technically* a syntax *error*, but it is incorrect syntax for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
options = '<option value="paphos">Paphos</option>';
          '<option value="larnaca">Larnaca</option>';
```

Those are *two separate statements*.  More clearly illustrated by modifying only the whitespace:

```
options = '<option value="paphos">Paphos</option>';

'<option value="larnaca">Larnaca</option>';
```

The first sets the `options` variable to that one string.  The second statement is just a string, by itself, not doing anything.  So after these two statements execute, `options` has only been set to that first value.

I think you want to *concatenate* your values instead:

```
options = '<option value="paphos">Paphos</option>' +
          '<option value="larnaca">Larnaca</option>';
```

Or, alternatively:

```
options = '<option value="paphos">Paphos</option>';
options += '<option value="larnaca">Larnaca</option>';
```

Which would perform the concatenation across two statements.  How you choose to do it depends on what you think is more readable and easier to maintain, really.